# ASP.NET server side show JS Alert box, doesn't work when using partial post back

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have put the following method in my master page. It works when I call it on a full post back, but when I call it from a updatePanel's asyncPostBack no alert is shown.

```
    public void ShowAlertMessage(String message)
    {
        string alertScript = 
            String.Format("alert('{0}');", message);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Key", alertScript, true);
    }
```

What do I need to do so it works on partial post backs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to register the script with the `ScriptManager`:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "alert('hi')", true);
```

Here is some more information:

[Inline Script inside an ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2007/09/17/inline-script-inside-an-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
protected void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string alertScript = "alert('Hello');";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Key", alertScript, true);
}
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="BtnClick" Text="Test" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```